# includes called on a relation in AR. Does it scope on the relation or the entire database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an odd situation where an has_many association yields me an empty collection but a scope on an empty collection yields me a record. Any idea what is going on?

```
class Person
  has_many :apples

end

Class Apple
  belongs_to :person

  scope :rotten, -> { includes(pit: :seed).where(seeds: { seed_type_id: Seedtype.edible.id})
end
```

Inside the Person model:

```
=> Apple.all
[
    [0] #<Apple:0x007fdff8b49b70> {
                           :id => 1,
                      :user_id => 1,
    }
]

=> apples
[]

=> apples.rotten
[
    [0] #<Apple:0x007fdff8b49b70> {
                           :id => 1,
                      :user_id => 1
    }
]
```

Any ideas as to what is going on?

My guess is that when I call apple.includes... the includes is not actually being called on the empty collection but the class. Is that right?

Comment: Apple.all and person.apples are different things

Comment: Which result is the anomalous one ?

Comment: you mean person.apples return nothing but person.apples.rotten returns some values ??